# Sencha Touch unit testing best practice?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, cordova, sencha-touch, extjs

I would like to do unit testing on my Sencha Touch application, I have found plenty of information online, but not any promising guide that was worth following.

Are there any resources to recommend? I am keen on using QUnit, could you please provide me with any example? (E.g. how could I test that a class that inherits from Ext.Panel has been created?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sencha have written an article on unit testing here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/testing), it's geared towards Ext JS but I'm sure you can adapt it to Sencha Touch.

Answer (score 1):

Automating Unit Tests:
  - http://www.sencha.com/blog/automating-unit-tests

UI Testing a Sencha App:
  - http://www.sencha.com/blog/ui-testing-a-sencha-app/

Building Unit Tests for Sencha Apps:
  - https://vimeo.com/58665998

I'm not sure anything specific to QUnit has been written (a lot revolves around Jasmine), but the content can be applied to any framework.